# Возврат переназначенной константы через дочерний класс

Tags: php, ооп

```
class CNetwork
{
    const NETWORK_NAME = '';

    public function getNetworkName() {
        return self::NETWORK_NAME;
    }
}
class CTwitter extends CNetwork
{
    const NETWORK_NAME = 'TWITTER';
}
```

Если я взываю метод getNetworkName из CTwitter, то метод возвращает значения из родительского класса. Как сделать так, чтобы унаследованный метод возвращал переназначенную константу?

Comment: `late static binding`  и ключевое слово `static`.

Comment: Не `self::NETWORK_NAME` а `static::NETWORK_NAME`

Comment: @u_mulder Преобразуйте свой комментарий в ответ, я выберу его в качестве правильного.